# How do I detect selected items in a Telerik grid & updated their values in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I am doing a task related to telerik grid. In that I have added checkboxes as item templates. When I check the box and if I click on submit, that should be updated in database.

Here is the code I have tried.

aspx:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Is Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsActive" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkIsActive_OnCheckedChanged" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
public void chkIsActive_OnCheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkIsActive = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow Row = (GridViewRow)chkIsActive.NamingContainer;
    string cid = Row.Cells[1].Text;
    bool status = chkIsActive.Checked;
}
```

Error which I am getting:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

Please resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to cast a telerik Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem to a normal gridviewrow, cast it to Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem instead.

```
Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem Row = (Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem)chkIsActive.NamingContainer;
```